# How to restart nginx via nodejs code on linux?

Tags: node.js, linux, nginx

I have build a nodejs application that manages my reverse proxy configuration.
Now I am at the problem that I don't now how to restart ngnix via nodejs to let the config changes have effect.

What is the way to restart a linux process (via systemctl maybe) more precise nginx via nodejs?

Comment: Spawn `systemctl reload nginx` via the built in [`child_process`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v14.x/docs/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options) module?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you make changes to the Nginx configuration, you need to restart or reload the webserver processes. Execute the following command to restart the Nginx service:

**sudo systemctl restart nginx**

Nginx can also be directly controlled with signals . For example, to reload the service, you can use the following command:

sudo /usr/sbin/nginx -s reload

sudo systemctl start nginx

Comment: yeah, I know about that but I wanted to know how I can do that with nodejs. Is my question not clear enough?

Comment: you need to write pipeline to restart nginx via node, can you gulp or grunt